# Potential pollution of Global` context in fresh kernel

Tags: bugs, contexts

****Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1****

The bug is also present in 12.2.0 and resolved in 12.3.0 on Mac OS X x86 (64-bit).

---

If I evaluate, with a fresh kernel

```
Names["Global`*"]
```

I get

> ```
> {"rhs", "z"}
> ```

I think this is not caused by any packages in `$UserBaseDirectory` or `$BaseDirectory`, because if I evaluate the same expression under V9.0.1, which has the same strings for these variables (directories), I get

```
Names["Global`*"]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

As expected.

I was wondering if others are getting the same result. `rhs` and `z` do not have values, but still I am a bit concerned about the safety of

```
Remove["Global`*"]
```

when certain functions may depend on the existence of these symbols in Global`. For example if I set

```
sys`f[Global`xxxx_] := Global`xxxx
```

and evaluate

```
Remove[Global`xxxx]
```

then the following looks a bit scary

```
 sys`f // Definition
```

> ```
> sys`f[Removed[xxxx]:_]:=Removed[xxxx]
> ```

`` sys`f `` still works, but I still think it may lead to trouble (e.g. with `Save`).

Kirma came up with the nice idea of testing this on the cloud. I get

```
Apply[And, 
 MemberQ[CloudEvaluate[Names["Global`*"]], #] & /@ {"z", "rhs"}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

But there are many other symbols in the `` Global` ``  context there. So, is this a bug?

Comment: On V10 I get `{FOO, list, msgs, rhs, z}`

Comment: @Pickett That should be ``Names[Global`*]`` (with the *). Which one did you try? By the way when I evaluate it again after the `CloudEvaluate` call, there are more symbols in ``Global` ``

Comment: But removing these symbols and trying `CloudEvaluate` again does work, despite my speculation.

Comment: In v.10.0.0 under Win7 x64 I get `{"rhs", "z"}`.

Comment: `$Version`

"10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)"

`Names["Global\`*"]`

{"rhs", "z"}

Comment: I have seen both `{list, msgs, rhs, z}` and `{"rhs", "z"}`. Win-7 64.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom :/ I knew what it should have been but I mistyped and somehow didn't notice. Now I can reproduce your result.

Comment: Nevermind my earlier comment, I get `{"list", "msgs", "rhs", "z"}` under Linux.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries thanks for adding the [tag:bugs] tag. I agree it is appropriate

Comment: Indeed. Are you going to report this to WRI?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries reported!

Comment: Same on Windows 7.

Comment: Can confirm this happens on OS X in V10 but not in V9. Immediately after stat-up the the `Global` context seems to be a bit dirty.

Comment: I confirm in Win7,Mma10. It returned in my case `{list, msgs, rhs, z}`. However, when I typed these words in Mma everything appeared in blue as if Mma does not know about it.

Comment: Seems to be solved in V10.0.1 (Win7-64).

Comment: This seems to have popped up again; with `$Version == "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"` I get `{a}`.

Comment: ... and it's resolved in `"12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)"`.

Comment: @evanb thank you in particular for this last message, I will not send a report to WRI then

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom sure!

Comment: @evanb is it? I get {"candidates", "InterGR", "IP4AddressPattern", "IP4AddrToInteger", 
"linkHost", "linkName", "linkNameComponents", "pos"};  Why pos?? for 12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)

Comment: I do not get those; I get {}.

Answer (score 5):

I reported this problem to Wolfram technical support, and I have received the following response (edited for brevity).

> I was able to reproduce the issue you have reported. I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided.

I have tagged the question with [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs).

#### Update

This bug appears to be fixed in V10.0.1