# Need some explanation of "Global`*"

Tags: variable-definitions

When I start a new notebook, I enter

```
Names["Global`*"]
```

I get this

```
{"list", "msgs", "rhs", "z"}
```

Then I enter,

```
mydummy[x_, y_, model_] := Module[
      {ans, j},
      ans = Sum[x[[j]], {j, 1, y}]

  ];
Names["Global`*"]
```

I get this:

```
{"ans", "ans$", "j", "j$", "list", "model", "model$", "msgs", "mydummy", "rhs", "x", "x$", "y", "y$", "z"}
```

I dont really know the difference between `x` and `x$` here. I don't know any of the difference between the variables and the one with an extra `$`.

I check

```
?j
?j$
```

Ok, one of them is 'Temporary'.

Here are my questions:

1 - Are they all saved in RAM during the session?
2 - What's the point of saving these 'Temporary' (Global) variables? I thought when declaring them to be local using Module[], they would be thrown away after my execution.

3 - Why do we have `x` and `y` at first place? I only defined `mydummy`, which is a function. So I only want the 'final' value when it's evaluated.

4 - If the `x` and `y` are of any use, how do I access them? I tried

```
x
```

It does not tell me anything?

5 - If I define a new function,

```
mydummy2[x_, y_, model_] := Module[
  {ans, j},
  ans = Sum[x[[j]], {j, 1, y}]

]
```

Now

```
Names["Global`*"]
```

which 'x' is which?

6 - Sometimes, I get Global variables like

```
tmp$1
    tmp$20
tmp$300
```

To me, they are all 'local' to a Module. But it's in the list when I use 'Names["Global`*"]', why are they there? Can I remove them during a long calculation? How to remove and what's the downside of removing them?

7 - Do I need to declare $j$ within a Module, if it's a dummary index value, like this

```
ans=Table[Sum[j],{j,1,3}]
(* or *)
ans=Sum[x[[j]],{j,1,3}]
```

8 - Lastly, when i first started Mathematica, what are the "list,msgs,rhs,z" variables?

Sorry if this seems really silly. But I do want to understand this, as I have long codes, it seems sometimes it's using too much memory. I am not sure if it's caused by those 'local' variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I suspect you are running *Mathematica* 10.0.0 and are experiencing these issues:

- [Potential pollution of Global` context in fresh kernel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54658/121)
- [Is garbage collection broken in version 10.0.0?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58375/121)

In version 10.0.1 I get:

```
Names["Global`*"]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

And then:

```
mydummy[x_, y_, model_] := Module[{ans, j}, ans = Sum[x[[j]], {j, 1, y}]];

Names["Global`*"]
```

> ```
> {"ans", "ans$", "j", "j$", "model", "mydummy", "x", "y"}
> ```

The remaining names can all be explained as expected behavior.  Every Symbol name that appears that does not correspond to an existing Symbol in the [`$ContextPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$ContextPath.html)

is created in the current [`$Context`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$Context.html). See:

- [Local variables in Module leak into the Global context](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8295/121)

This explains `{"ans", "j", "model", "mydummy", "x", "y"}`.

The remaining two: `{"ans$", "j$"}` are more tricky; I believe they are created by the automatic renaming mechanism that applies to nested scoping constructs, here `SetDelayed` and `Module`.  See:

- [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/121)

I shall try to address all of your question on a point-by-point basis if I have time.  I think those links should give you plenty to read for the moment, and right now it is time for me to eat. :-)

Comment: You are absolutely right that I am using V10.0.0. As I am very new to Mathematica, I was not aware this was a bug related. I just thought it might be some of my code. Because I have scoping structure, and sometimes it is causing me memory overflow on my 8GB RAM.   I will definitely take some time to read the links.

Comment: Just tested on V 10.0.1. `Names["Global`*"]` works fine now. That's sorted!