# Global` context not empty at startup in v10.2.0

Tags: bugs, contexts

**Bug introduced in 10.2 and persisting through 10.2 or later**

---

*Note that the analysis of this problem revealed a different problem than in [Potential pollution of Global` context in fresh kernel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54658/potential-pollution-of-global-context-in-fresh-kernel) (see answers). Despite the initial impression that is reflected in the title, the `` "Global`" `` context is empty at startup.*

[image]

Bug again in V10.2?

Fresh kernel.

Linux is OK:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure your `init.m` is clean?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I did not modify anything in the file and it is confirmed by many other users from the Chinese community. So we wonder if it is a bug again....I found the same thing in an earlier version, which was posted in SE as well.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce, but only if a front end is in use.  A kernel running in a terminal is fine.  Why don't you report it to WRI?

Comment: Confirmed in v10.2 under Mac OS X 10.10.4.

Comment: @Szabolcs I dont know how and just want to double check it is not a problem only occurs within the Chinese community, as we are all using Chinese versions of windows. Just want to be absolutely sure.

Comment: You can contact support: http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/

Comment: Out of curiosity I grepped the installation directory and m7res appears only in PLI.mx in SystemFiles/Components/PLI.  Does anyone know what PLI stands for?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks.

Comment: @Szabolcs The PLI.mx file says `(*This is a Mathematica binary dump file. It can be loaded with Get.*)`

Comment: This has happened before. In V10.0.0 is was worse.

Comment: @m_goldberg Yes, exactly. I wonder why WRI does not check this. They should make this on their "checklist" if they have one. :)

Comment: @Szabolcs PLI stands for ["Programmable Linguistic Interface"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ProgrammableLinguisticInterface.html). It is in the ``Semantic` `` context, which contains things like parsers for various inputs into `Dataset` objects, although it is not clear to me exactly what it does here or how it works (it seems to be mostly cloud-related). See symbols under ``Semantic`PLIDump` ``.

Comment: Hmm...``Names["Global`*"]`` returns an empty list.  I wonder if the symbols are introduce by `Information`?

Comment: I just want to respond to the closure and justify my casting of a re-open vote. This is the same *type* of bug as in the other question, but it is not the *same bug*. The last one was fixed; this one isn't, and it isn't a regression either, because the symbols are different, as are the circumstances under which the leak appears.

Comment: @Oleksandr Might as well have two questions: one for `sym` and one for `$m7res`, since these two leaks happen to be *separate bugs*, coming from different pieces of code and not introduced at the same time. Each of them can be triggered to appear in `Global\`` independently of the other. One is currently fixed in the development version, the other is being looked into.

Comment: @ilian that's possible. If the second bug doesn't get fixed before the next release, then I'd support that. But for the time being I don't think there's very much to be gained, from our perspective as users, in having separate questions so long as the bugs aren't independently observable. (After all, this is not a formal bug tracker, but a way for users to know whether unexpected behavior is due to a bug or not.) If you have a test case for the second bug that differentiates it from the first in a way that a user could feasibly observe, by all means, please post that as a separate question.

Comment: I agree it wouldn't be very useful and I didn't think that, from a user's perspective, the symptoms, underlying causes and impact sufficiently differed from the earlier question (so I voted to mark as a duplicate though formally it constitutes a separate bug, even two). But perhaps not being fixed at the moment is an important distinction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the symbols `sym` and `$m7res` are created by [`Information`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Information.html).  They are not present when the kernel is started.

Fresh kernel 1:

```
Quit[]

Names["Global`*"]
(*  {}  *)
```

[image]

Fresh kernel 2:

```
Quit[]

foo = Trace[
   Information["Global`*"],
   TraceInternal -> True];

foo[[8, 3, 5, 7, 2, 9, 18, 65, 2, 1, 3, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 3, 3, 6, 2, 8, 
  12, 10, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 76]]

foo[[8, 3, 5, 7, 2, 9, 19, 14, 2, 3, 7, 785]]
```

[image]

Warning: If you try turning on `General::newsym`, you will discover that an overwhelming number of new symbols are created.  (You can turn off `General::stop` if you are really interested in seeing them all.)

Comment: Somebody forgot to make his variables private…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I'm surprised they're still tinkering with `Information`.

Comment: To be fair, the output of `??` in old *Mathematica* didn't have the fancy formatting. Clearly, they are trying to spruce it up.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. That formatting has been around for a few major releases, at least since V8.  It may have changed slightly.  I wouldn't be able to remember or notice, probably.

Comment: I was thinking version 5 or so as "old", actually. :D (Sorry, must've been the nostalgia post I wrote earlier.) It was version 6 where I first saw the nicer formatting, IIRC.

Comment: What an oddity. Good job in narrowing this down. I suppose it also suggests that a huge number of symbols are being created all the time in obscure contexts, most of them having no usefully persistent definitions and never to be used again. I wonder what impact all of this has on performance?

Comment: Would you know if it is possible to modify one of the *Mathematica* installation files to make these symbols private, so they don't show up in the `Global`   context?

Comment: @QuantumDot My *guess* is that it's the file `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Contents", "SystemFiles", 
  "Kernel", "SystemResources", $SystemID, "mainload.mx"}]`, assuming `$SystemID` works on other systems the way it does on mine. I don't think you can change mainload.mx (safely).  You might put `Remove[sym, $m7res]` or `Remove["Global`*"]` in your [init.m](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html), assuming it is [executed after everything else on startup](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframSystemSessions.html).