# Why global name context in 13.3 is not empty?

Tags: kernel, kernel-startup

Today I tried 13.3.0 and immediately find that global name context again is not empty, i.e.

```
Names["Global`" <> "*"]
(*out*) {"res"}

$Version
(*out *) 13.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)
```

It is not a first time when this happens. See for example, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202841/why-does-args-symbol-exist-in-a-fresh-kernel) and links therein.

Since when developing package as a last line I include check if private and global symbols don't overlap

```
If[Names["Global`" <> "*"] =!= {}, Print["wrong"]]
```

this becomes a bit irritating.
Can anybody confirm this is indeed the case or some catching byproduct?

Comment: MMA 13.3  Windows 10: Global contains: {res,"WriteStatusLine","SetNotebookStatusLine",x}

Comment: The result on my MMA 13.3.0 Win10-64 is `{"dir", "res"}`.

Comment: I see `{next}`. You can always start with `Remove["Global\`*"]`

Comment: I also get {"res"} in version 13.3 on Windows 11. Looks like one of the devs made a small mistake.

Comment: The diversity of responses here is certainly curious, however.